# Who initiates an authorization code flow?

Tags: oauth2

I'd like to understand OAuth 2.0 in more detail and especially the authorization code flow. This might be nit-picking but according to [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) the **client** initiates the flow.

> (A) The client initiates the flow by directing the resource owner's
> user-agent to the authorization endpoint.

But isn't it really the resource owner who initiates the flow by clicking a button like `Connect with service xyz` or `Import photos from abc` on the client application site when requesting authorization?

I mean it's this button click that sends out a HTTP GET originating from the resource owners machine/IP, right?

```
GET https://www.auth-server.com/oauth2/authorize?

client_id=18f4ad63-01fa-41ae-b632-092a8f5d340b&
redirect_uri=https://www.awesome-printservice.com/callback&
scope=openid photos.read
response_type=code&
response_mode=query&
nonce=ugasq9v1bq&
```

Comment: the diagram is pretty confusing by labeling the "resource server" as "resource owner".  The text is correct, but the diagram is confusing (to me anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the example of signing into your site (https://example.net) *via* your Google account.

In this case, you [and, by extension, your digital "user agent": Firefox or Chrome] are the "resource owner"; ExampleNET is the "client" (and also the "relying party").

**The client, ExampleNET, initiates the flow** by directing you, the resource owner, to emit that HTTP request you described.

Sounds weird? Look closer at that request.

See the `nonce` field? That had to be prepared by the *client*. More significantly (though missing from your example), in the same vein is the [`state` field](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#state-param): also prepared by the client as they prepare to initiate the flow by [re]directing the resource owner to that big URL.

Now, they may or may not have "warmed the flow up" by pre-initializing the nonce (which, if they're using, they *should* be recording to check it against later), or by quickly generating it when the resource owner expresses intent to use that flow (by *e.g.*, loading the Login page), and they may have *done this* in response to activity from you which clearly signaled intent to start that flow (such as *e.g.* clicking the Sign In Via Google link...)

but they're still the ones initiating the flow by *giving you* the (**potentially ephemeral**) necessaries to take the—from the *resource owner's* point-of-view—"first" step of the login flow. That's why the client is described as initiating it here.